# Can we estimate the propotion of outcome (binary) variance explained by multiple predictors using summary statistics only?

Tags: regression, logistic, variance, prediction, odds

A toy example: We aim to predict the onset of stroke by body weight and age. We know that:

1. 1-SD increment of weight increases the odds of stroke by 20% i.e. standardized coefficient of regression stroke~weight+intercept is log(1.2)
2. 1-SD increment of age increases the odds of stroke by 15%
3. Pearson correlation between weight and age is 0.1
4. The prevalence of stroke in the population is 1%

Is it possible to estimate the proportion of variance of stroke explained by weight and age together, without individual data? If not, what else information should we have? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of regression was used to estimate those coefficients? Logistic regression doesn't give you the change in risks; it gives you the change in odds. How do you want to measure proportion of variance explained?

Comment: @Noah My bad, I messed up odds ratio and risk ratio. These coefficients are calculated by genetic epidemiology analysis, and the interpretation is equivalent to Logistic regression (alteration of Odds per 1-SD increment in predictor). For variance explained, I'm thinking about a way similar to the definition of heritability "the phenotypic difference is determined by genetic difference by **%". Maybe it's the pseudo R2 for logistic regression stroke~weight+age+iuntercept?

Comment: "Variance explained" is not meaningful for logistic regression.